# Embed Flask-Admin CRUD view into site

Tags: python, flask, crud, flask-admin

I would like to build user-facing CRUD functionality for just a couple of models into my app.

Flask-Admin is amazing and my ideal scenario would be to just copy the existing CRUD functionality of Flask-Admin into one of the pages in my app.

For example if I could copy the table portion of the image below into my app and embed other content around it (like my site's global navbar, etc).

[image]

I understand that Flask-Admin has some options for [over-riding the built-in templates](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#overriding-the-built-in-templates), but I am not sure how I could use this ability for my purpose.

I don't simply want to make my admin panel look nicer, I want to pull the CRUD capabilities from the admin panel and build them into the main portion of my app and save myself the hassle of developing all of this CRUD capability myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created [Subview](https://github.com/artemShelest/flask-admin-subview) module for Flask-Admin that could help with this. For now it lacks full CRUD support from the view, though. If it does help, you can create custom actions, which are supported.